# Base cabinet ends at window trim

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-counters

Im planning on converting a small "office" space next to our kitchen into a walkin pantry. the wall is 95" long however on the corner there is an exterior window. the window trim starts 10.5" from the wall.

what are options for ending a cabinet run on that long wall?

1. leave a gap and cover the gap with the countertop at an angle?
2. Get a custom 9inch deep cabinet
3. other options?

[image: cabinet wall]

Comment: Pantry as in storing food?  Food does not like light, so can remove window trim.  Trim is just for looking nice(and hide boo-boos).

Comment: From the [help] section on [what to not ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), _avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid: ... “What’s your favorite ______?”_ So far, you've got two answers (yes, one is mine) and all of them are equally valid. This is too broad and there really is no objectively "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

**3c:** Purchase or build shallow open faced shelves to fill the gap but not run into the trim.

**3d:** Create vertical storage for cookie sheets and other large, thin items.

**3e:** Leave it open to store larger, odd shaped items like brooms and folding step stools

Answer (score 0):

**3a:** Remove the window trim and mud it flush to the window frame so the window is a hole *in* the flat wall, not a framed hole sticking *out* of the wall surface. "**Trimless window**" seems to be a search term that works for examples. Butt your cabinets right up the the wall. Overlap the window a few inches if just losing the trim doesn't get you the space you need.

**3b:** Remove the window itself and make it wall, or a much smaller window. (More work since you have to deal with exterior flashing, siding, etc.)